# Can I force git diff to treat a file as a copy?

Tags: git, version-control, diff

The diff functionality in git has "copy detection"--if it detects that a new file is actually a (possibly modified) copy of an existing file, the diff output shows the differences between the source file and the new file rather than just a bunch of additions from a blank file to the new file.

As far as I can tell, `git diff` uses some heuristics to detect this situation. Unfortunately it is not detecting a particular new file as a copy of another file because I guess it has changed too much. I'd still like to view the diff as though it were a copy. Is there a way to inform `git diff` that the new file is a copy of another so that it will do this for me?

Answer (score 2):

`git diff` (at least my version 1.5.6 does) comes with the switch `--find-copies-harder`, which does more cpu-intensive copy detection than the regular `-C` does.

Comment: I tried --find-copies-harder and it still didn't detect my new file as a copy of an existing file.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to make sure it was added to the git repo.

Also if you know the original file, why not use diff directly?

Comment: Using diff directly works great, but I'd like the diff to be included in my `git diff` results.

Comment: has the new file been added to the git repo?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put **both** files in the diff?

something like

```
git diff --stat -p --find-copies-harder -- src/OldFile.java src/main/NewFile.java
```

I imagine you did, just in case...